# .Net Core API returning 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, http-status-code-500

I have a .NET core web api. It works as expected when requesting from Postman but returning

```
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

when requested from other React JS client. I have already enabled CORS in the `Startup.cs` like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc();
            ...
}
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            ...
}
```

But still getting the `Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error`. I have been trying to solve this issue for too long. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This is almost certainly due to an exception - you should look in the server logs to find out more details about what's going wrong.

Comment: This fixed my issue. There's an error in my code. I just found it from the server Event Viewer. Thank you @JonSkeet. You've just saved my life.

Answer (score 1):

add this in your configure method:

```
// global cors policy
        app.UseCors(x => x
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
```

if its not solved then add a custom middleware and check your request you can use ilogger for logging exception.

follow this link for middleware: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/how-to-add-custom-middleware-aspnet-core